# Difference between character and byte stream translation to character for characters that can be represented with 1byte

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, reader

From the java documentation
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html),
It says that:

> The character stream uses the byte stream to perform the physical I/O, **while the character stream handles translation between characters and bytes**

How does this happen,when the **character stream class** `read()` and `write()` bytes(2) just as the **byte stream class** does,but 1 at a time and they all return **integer types** which can be mapped to **char**.

- Assuming for all characters that can be encoded with 1byte
- What is the **special translation here** apart from the number of byte and how does it differ from **byte stream conversion to character** or what handles translation between character and byte for the byte stream?

-

Answer (score 0):

- Binary data: `byte, InputStream/OutputStream`;
- Text (Unicode): `String, char` (UTF-16 2 bytes)`, Reader/Writer`.

This means there should always be a conversion between both, using the Charset encoding of the binary data.

What is irritating:

- `InputStream.read()` returns an int: a byte value, or -1 = end-of-file.

Single byte encodings as they happen under Windows have the same first 128 chars, in pure 7-bits ASCII, `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`. But they differ for the remaining 128 bytes (Greek, Russian, Slowakian, Norwegian etcetera).

Java made the decision to internally use Unicode, so all scripts can be combined in one String.

> Hence there always is a conversion. And String should never be used for non-text binary data.